# French exchange year in Sweden

Tags: students, study, sweden

I am a french student who will spend the next year in Sweden as an exchange student so I tried to make some friends from there by using language learning app / website but.. It's really difficult to get some attention of people from Scandinavian countries. It seems that there is a specific way to get in touch with them, I mean people from western european countries are way more 'direct' I guess. So I would like to know if there are some things I shouldn't talk about with someone from Sweden. I am quite afraid that it's the same when I'll be there.

Comment: I'm a bit torn on this question. "How do I make friends in XXXX country" is a very open question. It depends on so many factors that have nothing to do with expatriates (such as your own personality, natural attractiveness, hobbies and interests, etc...) that I'm not sure we can give you good advice here.

Comment: Yes you're totally right but there are some things that I can say to an american and not to a french, for example in France it's not usual to talk about money when it's pretty common and a proof of success in US. My question was oriented on this way :)

Comment: Here's a third party page with a bunch of info: http://www.executiveplanet.com/sweden-2/. In particular, the page on [conversation](http://www.executiveplanet.com/sweden-2/sweden_conversation-2/) is probably helpful for starting out.

Comment: It was very interesting to read, thanks @GregHewgill